# Why does GNU Make try to compile an object file that doesn't exist, for a rule without a recipe?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

If you run `make test` on the following Makefile (with an otherwise empty directory):

```
test.%:
    @echo $*

test: test.dummyextension
```

you get the following output:

```
dummyextension
o
cc   test.o test.dummyextension   -o test
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'test.o'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'test.dummyextension'
clang: error: no input files
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

**Why?**

I suspect it has something todo with implicit rules, but I searched `make -p` on my machine, and can't find any implicit rules that match `%: %`. I would expect the output to simply be `dummyextension`, but it's almost like there's a phantom `test.o` file in my directory (despite my checking ten times that there is not).

If you put a `;` after the `test.dummyextension` prerequisite, or add any content to the `test` rule, everything works as expected. This is the minimal failing example I can come up with, and I haven't a clue why you'd see this behaviour. Any ideas?

Comment: You asked make to build a target named `test` that does not exist and has no recipe. So make tries to use one of its implicit rules. As you have a pattern rule that could be used to generate `test.o` and `test.dummyextension` without any more prerequisites, this is the way make selects: C compilation and link. So, make tries 1. to create `test.dummyextension` and `test.o` with your pattern rule (thus the `dummyextension` and `o` output), 2. to create `test` by linking `test.o` and `test.dummyextension` prerequisites. As none exist you get linker (`clang`) errors.

Comment: Declare `test` as [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) to explain make that it is not a real file. make will not try to build it any more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make can chain multiple rules to create a target.  In this case it has the following built-in rule:

```
%: %.o
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

This tells make that it can make `test` if it can find a way to make intermediate file `test.o`.  So now it looks for a way to make `test.o` and it sees your pattern rule `test.%:`, which matches with stem `o`.  So it has found a way!

You have also told make that `test` needs `test.dummyextension`, so it looks for a way to make that and again the pattern `test.%:` matches, this time with stem `dummyextension`.

So make first runs the `test.%` recipe twice to make the two prereqs.  Then it runs the `%: %.o` recipe to make the final target.  The `$^` in the recipe is all prerequisites, so both `test.o`, gained from the built-in pattern rule, and `test.dummyextension`, gained by the explicit dependency in your Makefile, appear in the command.

You can test this by using the `-r` flag to disable built-in rules and then add the above pattern rule manually to your Makefile.

The key points to understand here are:

A line of the form:

```
test: test.dummyextension
```

Only adds a dependency to a target.  It **is not** a rule to make the target.  That can come from elsewhere.  Make does not see this and decide `test` should be created with a blank recipe.

A stanza of the form:

```
test: test.dummyextension
        ;
```

This **is** a rule to make the target.  Being an explicit rule it has a higher priority than a pattern rule that might also match.  This does tell make it has found the rule to make `test` using the recipe `;` and it stops looking for another rule.

Make will search for an implicit rule to make any target if it does not find an explicit one.  If you don't want it to do this, you can either give it an explicit rule, like above, or declare the target as phony, with `.PHONY: target`.  Implicit rules are not searched for phony targets.

Comment: Aha! I hadn't clocked that `%.o` could match `test.%` - thanks for the thorough explanation!